# Hide, then Expand or Show a column in HTML

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to have a table with lets say 10 total columns, but when the table first renders, I want it to only show 7 of the 10, or hide 3 of the columns from the middle lets say (not the end 3 or the first). Then, there is a button or something that if they click on, it will expand the table and insert those columns in their correct places.

Is this possible to do? I am using jQuery. I know that there is a show and hide function in jQuery but that seems to apply to objects only, such as a paragraph or a table as a whole, not specific elements.

Currently I have this:

```
<table id="tableone" border="1">
    <tr class="del">
        <td>Row 0 Column 0</td>
        <td >Row 0 Column 1</td>
        <td >Row 0 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="del">
        <td>Row 1 Column 0</td>
        <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="del">
        <td>Row 2 Column 0</td>
        <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="del">
        <td>Row 3 Column 0</td>
        <td>Row 3 Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 3 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="del">
        <td>Row 4 Column 0</td>
        <td>Row 4 Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 4 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="del">
        <td>Row 5 Column 0</td>
        <td>Row 5 Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 5 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what have u tried? show some code to debug other than markup.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using jquery, give some similar classes to the columns which you want to show after the click, 
if i understood correct, you can try below

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $("class_of_the_colums").toggle();
}
```

you can look at jquery for more information : http://www.jquery.com

Comment: So have a different class for each column?

Comment: give similar classes to columns which you want to hide and show on a button click. colums with same class will get displayed/hidden on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors to only select specific TDs inside all TRs as follow:
(The count starts at 1, not zero!)

```
​$('tr td:nth-child(2)').hide()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
```

When you want the column to be shown again, you can do:

```
​$('tr td:nth-child(2)').show()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
```

If you are planning on changing the number of columns to hide, or their positions, you'll be better off with assigning a class to these columns and using `$('.className').hide()`, but on the same wavelength as the example above, you'd do:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
        // Creates a reference to columns 2 and 3;
        var $columnsToHide = $('tr td:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(3)');
        // Hides them
        $columnsToHide.toggle();
        // if element with id buttonID is clicked
        $('#buttonID').on('click', function() {
            // show the columns
            $columnsToHide.toggle();
        });
    }​);
```

Comment: Okay so that works, but how do i auto-hide columns 2 and 3 lets say on the render from the start when the table loads up? And then they'd click show and it would show up

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you use unique IDs for any and all elements you wish to hide like:

```
<table id="tableone" border="1"> 
<tr id="del1"> 
<td>Row 0 Column 0</td> 
<td >Row 0 Column 1</td> 
<td >Row 0 Column 2</td> 
</tr> 
<tr id="del2"> 
<td>Row 1 Column 0</td> 
<td>Row 1 Column 1</td> 
<td>Row 1 Column 2</td> 
</tr> 
<tr id="del3"> 
<td>Row 2 Column 0</td> 
<td>Row 2 Column 1</td> 
<td>Row 2 Column 2</td> 
</tr> 
<tr id="del4"> 
<td>Row 3 Column 0</td> 
<td>Row 3 Column 1</td> 
<td>Row 3 Column 2</td> 
</tr> 
<tr id="del5"> 
<td>Row 4 Column 0</td> 
<td>Row 4 Column 1</td> 
<td>Row 4 Column 2</td> 
</tr> 
<tr id="del6"> 
<td>Row 5 Column 0</td> 
<td>Row 5 Column 1</td> 
<td>Row 5 Column 2</td> 
</tr>
```

Then, in your css styling, where you had .del you would replace with:

```
#del1,
#del2,
#del3,
#del4,
#del5,
#del6{
properties
}
```

Then with you jQuery you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#del3").hide();
$("#del4").hide();
});
```

And:

```
$("#id_of_button_that_will_show_the_hidden_elements").click(function(){
$("#del3").show();
$("#del4").show();
});
```

This would not work with your elements all being part of the same class as $(".del").hide(); will just hide all elements with that class.

Hope I helped =)

Comment: This is helpful, thankyou! But here I am only deleting the rows with the relevant ID....to delete columns, would I have assign a class to each <td> element?

Comment: Yes you can assign either a class or an id to the <td> elements, just remember that if you use classes jQuery will identify and apply the function you specify to ALL elements with that class. If you use id's be sure that no id is used more than once, the id is unique to each element and will cause problems if you assign it to more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function which does something like this :

```
function hssel(cls,from,fr,hs) {
  if ( from < 0 ) {
var chlds = $('tr.'+cls).parent().children().length;
  from = chlds + from;
  }
  for ( var i = from+1,fr = (from+fr)||from+1 ;i <= fr ;i++ ) {
    $('tr.'+cls+':nth-child('+i+')')[(hs=="show"?"show":"hide")]();
  }
}

//hssel("del",0) //would hide the first row with the class del
//hssel("del",0,3) //would hide the first three rows
//hssel("del",-3,3) //would hide the last three rows
//hssel("del",-3,3,"show"); //would show the last three rows
hssel("del",-3,3);
```

Here is an [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ujozob/edit#javascript,html) example
And here is the same function for columns ^^

```
function hssel(cls,from,fr,hs) {
  if ( from < 0 ) {
    var chlds = $('tr.'+cls+':first-child').children().length;
    console.log(chlds);
  from = chlds + from;
  }
  for ( var i = from+1,fr = (from+fr)||from+1 ;i <= fr ;i++ ) {
    $('tr.'+cls+' td:nth-child('+i+')')[(hs=="show"?"show":"hide")]();
  }
}
```

And the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ujozob/2/edit#javascript,html) example
the usage is the same as for the rows

Comment: oh damn i messed up cols and rows, my bad.